# URL String Get Directory

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that contains a URL:

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/Shared%20Documents/Test%20Plans/CC-12%20Test%20Plan.doc";
```

I am trying to get the url of the directory (ie remove the filename and keep the rest.)
I realize that this is probably pretty simple but I can't seem to find anything on it.

Desired result:

```
var url = "http://www.domain.com/Shared%20Documents/Test%20Plans/";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var resultUrl = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7RtH/) here

Comment: To match the desired result of BlueBird `... url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 ...` is correct :) .

Comment: Ah yes. I just verified it in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following expression:

```
location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + location.pathname
```

with the *current* URL displayed in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Use Substring as follow....

```
url=url.substring(0,url.lastindexof("/")-1);
```

Comment: Watch the capitalization. The methods are named `substring` and `lastIndexOf`.

Comment: ok..didn't check that..just wrote to give him idea...well changed it now...thanks